# What are iFrame policies?

Tags: security, web, web-deployment, websecurity

As I was brushing up my frontend skills, I stumbled upon a question about iFrame policies (https://www.quora.com/What-questions-are-often-asked-during-a-front-end-interview).

I googled, but could but found any clear explanation about what it is, what purpose it serves and how to use it?

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

In my company we have iFrame policies as iFrames come with several disadvantages reg. security as discussed for example here:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13341/security-issues-using-iframes

These policies are enforcing a common view on iFrames and regulations on how to use iFrames. This will improve awareness of all devs for these security issues and also improve security if they are well defined.

Comment: Thanks Kennuel for the quick reply. But could you give some context and details?

Comment: So often companies give out an advice how to use iFrames internally eg. which properties must be set on an iframe to be more secure.

Properties can be from, always use sandbox wit a certain property: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

to completly forbid iFrames - an advise how to use iFrames in general